# Problem with macro using \newcount in \caption

Tags: captions, counters

I have a macro `\foo` that performs arithmetic on it's argument:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{
    \newcount\tmpR
    \tmpR=#1
    \advance\tmpR by -1
    R{\number\tmpR}
}

\begin{document}

\foo{10}

\begin{figure*}
\caption{\foo{99}}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

This compiles with no errors. However, if I comment out the first call to `\foo{10}`, I get the following error from the macro call in the caption:

```
$ pdflatex mwe.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX)
restricted \write18 enabled.
    entering extended mode
(./mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9g> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./mwe.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \tmpR

l.15 \caption{\foo{99}}
```

What is the cause of this error, and how can I fix it? Is there a better way to write this macro?

Comment: Add `\protect` before `\foo{99}`. Otherwise declare `\foo` with `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to type `\foo{99}` instead of `\foo{98}`?

Comment: I need to refer to array indices that the rest of the relevant world considers zero-indexed, but I use MATLAB for data analysis, which is one-indexed. This allows me to use MATLAB indices in my LaTeX source code, while printing zero-indexed numbers, which I find just makes things clearer when referring to analysis code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are currently creating the counter `\tmpR` with every call to `\foo`. Create it once *outside* the definition of `\foo`. Also, you have to remember that the entry in `\caption` forms part of a moving argument, since it is written to the `.aux` and could end up in the LoF. So, you either need to `\protect` it (which prevents full expansion) or declare it as a robust command using `\DeclareRobustCommand`. Here's a take on your MWE

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{tmpR}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \setcounter{tmpR}{#1}% Set counter
  \addtocounter{tmpR}{-1}% Subtract from counter
  R\thetmpR% Print counter
}

\begin{document}

\foo{10}

\begin{figure*}
\caption{\foo{99}}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Here's a definition of `\foo` that achieves the same without counters:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\foo}[1]{%
  R\number\numexpr#1-1\relax% Print R<counter-1>
}
```

Comment: When I use your definition of `\foo` without counters, I don't need to use \protect or \DeclareRobustCommand. Does that mean that it is not fragile, or does the fragility for some reason just not cause a problem here?

Comment: @DanBecker: Without the use of counters the entire macro is expanded without problem, making it move with the arguments in the expected way (if you're adding `\listoffigures`). So yes, you don't need `\DeclareRobustCommand`. If you're doing anything else inside that macro that may be expansion-sensitive, `\protect`ion may be required.